# Как часто можно выпускать обновления приложения в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Вчера выпустили приложение в Google Play, а сегодня обнаружился большой косяк, который в спешке допустили в последний момент в приложении. Когда теперь можно выпустить обновление, чтобы это исправить? Просто слышал от одного человека, что якобы в плеймаркете обновления можно выпускать только раз в месяц. Так ли это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ограничений нет. Хоть каждую минуту обновляйте

Comment: Я не думаю что пользователям понравится обновление каждую минуту, поэтому лучше без фанатизма.

Comment: @pavel, обработка обновления занимает время. Несколько обновлений в минуту для юзера будут выглядеть как одно обновление, самое последнее. И сами обновления загружаются не сразу после его выхода, а только когда телефон юзера проверит, есть ли обновление